# Transforming a trapezium to a rectangle

Tags: projective-geometry, transformational-geometry

I need to transform a certain area of an image to a rectangle. I know the 4 corner coordinates of the trapezium area.

For example, this is the original image:

[image]

The x and y coordinates of points A, B, C, D are KNOWN.

I want to get an image like this:

[image]

A'B'C'D' is a rectangle and the x and y coordinates of points A', B', C', D' are also KNOWN.

The pixel A should move to A',

The pixel B should move to B',

The pixel C should move to C',

The pixel D should move to D'.

And the whole trapezium area should be transformed.

I'm sorry for bad English, I hope I could explain my question properly.

Comment: It appears in the illustration that $AD || BC$. Is this a general feature of the given data?

Comment: No, not a general feature. That is just a coincidence.

Comment: Without that condition, or a suitable version of it, one cannot achieve this with an affine transformation, which can only map three specified points in general position to three other specified points. (There are still infinitely many maps that will do the trick, but in general, that important and natural class is eliminated.)

Comment: Do you want to do following calculations on the picture or on the physical object? I guess you want to apply the calculations on the picture. If this is the case it completely depends on the camera's perspective/distortion the picture is taken with. It is possible to do following calcultions, but you will need to know some specifications of the camera the pictures are taken with.

Comment: @Ruts I'm making an optical mark reader (OMR). Teachers will take photos of mini optical forms on every exam paper and upload them to a private webpage. So I have to find a way to get the center coordinates of each marking circle on the image that was uploaded by the teacher. I'm currently working on an estimator. Here is some results from my estimator: http://oi58.tinypic.com/106levk.jpg I will easily solve it but it'd be great to use some mathematical formulas instead of an estimator.

Comment: With following [software](http://fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/skew/index.php) you can apply a skew to your image. All you need is the right parameters for the software. I think there is a way to calculate them using the black stripes on the side of the forms. Use computer vision software (I know [NI Vision](http://www.ni.com/vision/) is suitable) to track  the exact position of the black stripes.